# Whitespace before SOAP declaration

Tags: magento-1.8, soap, wsdl

We recently got a weird bug, and I'm wondering if anyone has encountered it.

When Magento generates the WSDL (v2) it started adding an extra whitespace before the  declaration.

This seems to pretty much break the internet :) .

I've grep'ed the entire code base and there are no whitespaces before XML decelerations anywhere.

Also, to add a topping, no errors are generated anywhere...

Thank you

Comment: + 1 for "break the internet". :)

Comment: Oh, I had this issue before. I'm looking at my old code. I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before. +1

Comment: I had this issue also once but for us an additional whitespace in the index.php was the problem. Did you check this file already?

Comment: Did you already solve your problem?

Comment: You need to remove UTF-8 BOM from project php files
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204765/elegant-way-to-search-for-utf-8-files-with-bom

Answer (score 1):

Try using this script to find the extra whitespace:

http://christian.roy.name/blog/removing-extra-whitespaces-bunch-php-files-using-ack-grep-and-emacs

You'll obviously need ssh for this and you should backup your files before running this or any script that edits your files

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly a blank line at the start of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any characters (spaces, tabs etc..) before `<?php` at beginning of *.php files.